# control nice level from within haskell

Tags: linux, haskell

Using Haskell is it possible to control the [nice](http://linux.die.net/man/2/nice) level from within a haskell program?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Let me hoogle that for you](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=nice).

The top link is:

```
nice :: Int -> IO ()
```

from [System.Posix.Process](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/unix/latest/doc/html/System-Posix-Process.html#v%3anice) (no documentation, but it's pretty obvious).

Comment: It might be useful to copy the relevant bit to this question. This is reminiscent of [LMGTFY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links) as it stands.

Comment: @tjameson so do I close the question or admit I forgot about hoogle in my question above and not as a comment?

Comment: @pyCthon - No. I meant the answer shouldn't just be a link. Your question's fine.